# Join XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt, join, xpath

I want to join two XML nodes based on some conditions (like SQL join between two tables).

Sample input XML:

```
<Sheet>
    <Section>
        <Header>
            <node>Campaign</node>
            <node>Placement</node>
            <node>KPI1</node>
            <node>KPI2</node>
        </Header>
        <Data>
            <Row>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Banner</value>
                <value>123</value>
                <value>134</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Popup</value>
                <value>234</value>
                <value>345</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Other</value>
                <value>345</value>
                <value>567</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Tour</value>
                <value>Banner</value>
                <value>123</value>
                <value>134</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Tour</value>
                <value>Popup</value>
                <value>234</value>
                <value>345</value>
            </Row>
        </Data>
    </Section>
    <Section>
        <Header>
            <node>Campaign</node>
            <node>Placement</node>
            <node>KPI41</node>
            <node>Spend</node>
        </Header>
        <Data>
            <Row>
            <value>Products</value>
                <value>Banner</value>
                <value>123</value>
                <value>2000000</value>

            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Popup</value>
                <value>234</value>
                <value>1000000</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Other</value>
                <value>345</value>
                <value>2000000</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Tour</value>
                <value>Banner</value>
                <value>123</value>
                <value>12</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Tour</value>
                <value>Popup</value>
                <value>234</value>
                <value>10</value>
            </Row>
        </Data>
    </Section>
</Sheet>
```

I want to join Section[1] and Section[2] based on Header node Campaign and placement (in SQL terms: `SELECT * FROM Section1 S1,Section2 S2 Where S1.Campaign = S2.Campaign AND S1.Placement = S2.Placement`). I am expecting the joined XML output.

Expected output like below:

```
<Sheet>
    <Section>
        <Header>
            <node>Campaign</node>
            <node>Placement</node>
            <node>KPI1</node>
            <node>KPI2</node>
            <node>Campaign</node>
            <node>Placement</node>
            <node>KPI41</node>
            <node>Spend</node>
        </Header>
        <Data>
            <Row>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Banner</value>
                <value>123</value>
                <value>134</value>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Banner</value>
                <value>123</value>
                <value>2000000</value>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Popup</value>
                <value>234</value>
                <value>345</value>
                <value>Products</value>
                <value>Popup</value>
                <value>234</value>
                <value>1000000</value>
            </Row>
           .......................
           like above
           ...................
        </Data>
    </Section>
</Sheet>
```

What is the best way to achieve this in XML? XPATH or XSLT?

Please help me with the best approach.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: i am looking for the better approach. Currently i created a XSLT to iterate all the <Row> in section1 and inside this iterated all <Row> from section 2 and copied <value> node. After both iteration completed i got 25 <Row> nodes (m*n) and then applied xpath to select <Row> where the condition value matching. I am looking for any other better approach.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your attempted XSLT, so that we can fix it instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: provide your xslt to find solution.